# What is the reporter saying at 5:42?

Tags: american-english, listening

At 5:42 of the following video

http://abcnews.go.com/Nightline/video/rambunctious-devoted-meet-philadelphia-eagles-fans-52810084

What is the reporter saying?
Is she saying like "do you think cold-wall(?) something at all(?)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what they're saying:

> — Do you think **the cold will slow them down** at all?
>   — Aww, I don't think there's gonna be a lot of Eagles fans feeling the cold or much of anything if they are to win the Super Bowl and I'm excited to watch it.

I think they're talking about the cold weather that's going to sweep the city of Philadelphia the day the Super Bowl is going to take place. She's asking the guy whether he thinks that it will prevent Eagles fans from being too rambunctious before, during and after the match. It also sounds like there's an *a* in front of *much of anything*, but *a much of anything* grammatically does not make any sense.

Comment: Not Philadelphia. Minneapolis, please. Are you Canadian? :)

Comment: But the Eagles fans at home in Philadelphia were celebrating outdoors in the streets; therefore, the weather in Philadelphia is relevant. The segment immediately after that sentence is an interview with a man who runs a bar in Philadelphia (not Minneapolis).